# Prove that $\kappa′(G) = \kappa (G)$ when $G$ is a simple graph with $\Delta (G) \leq 3$.

Tags: graph-theory

By theorem, $\kappa(G) \leq \kappa′(G)$ always. I need to show that $\kappa′(G) \leq  \kappa(G)$. I know that $\kappa(G)$ is the minimum size of a vertex cut. So I need to find an edge-cut that is the same size. But I am not sure how to get that started.

Comment: What is $\kappa(G)$ and $\kappa'(G)$? The context would be useful too...

Comment: So sorry... I always think the notation in my text is standard and, clearly, that is not always the case. κ(G) is the connectivity of a graph and κ′(G) is the edge connectivity of a graph.

Answer (score 2):

The main idea is the following: A vertex cut partitions the remaining vertices into at least two components. Consider an arbitray vertex of the cut. The precondition tells us, that its degree is at most $3$, then by the pidgeonhole principle, there is one component which is connected to the vertex by at most one edge. Then take those edges. (**drawing helps a lot!**)

However, you need to be careful with some degeneracies, e.g. if the vertices of the cut are adjacent between themselves. So, it just might be safest to simply check all cases:

$\kappa(G)=0$ is obvious as $G$ is disconnected in this case. Then $$\kappa(G)\leq\kappa'(G)\leq\Delta(G)\leq 3$$ 
implies the case $\kappa(G)=3$ immediately and shows that $\kappa(G) > 3$ is impossible.

So either $\kappa(G)=1$ or $2$. In each case, draw all configurations of two vertices with degree at most three and proceed as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that the graph $G$ is $k$-connected.

Let $S$ be the set of the vertices of the minimum vertex cut.
Let us assume that the $G - S $ has $j$ components.

Lemma :: All these vertices must have a neighbors in all the $j$ components.

But the maximum degree of any vertex is $3$. Hence, the value of $j$ can either be $2$ or $3$.

Case 1::  $ j=3$ ( $ \delta = \Delta =3 $)

Since $\delta = 3$, no vertex of $S$ can have more then $1$ adjacent vertex in a component. Hence there are $k$ edges from $S$ to any component. Removing any of these edges will make the graph disconnected. Hence $G$ is $k$-edge connected.

Case 2 :: $ j=2$ ( $\delta = 2$ or $3 $ )

Sub-case 1 :: $ \delta = 3 $
Let set $A$ and set $A'$  represent vertices of component_1 and component_2.Let us consider the vertices of $S$. Each vertex will be adjacent to 2 vertices of a component. Add this vertex to the set of vertices of that component ($A$ or $A'$ ). We can see that this will lead to $k$ edge between the set $A$ and $A'$. Hence, $G$ is k-edge connected.

Sub-case 2 :: $\delta = 2$
Since $\delta = 2$, no vertex of $S$ can have more then $1$ adjacent vertex in a component. Hence there are $k$ edges from $S$ to any component. Removing any of these edges will make the graph disconnected. Hence $G$ is $k$-edge connected.

When $\Delta =1 \implies \delta =1 $ , which $K_2$ which satisfy the theorem